# Parametrizing a self-intersecting tubular surface centred around a space curve to form a Klein bottle?

Tags: differential-geometry, frenet-frame, klein-bottle

As part of my math project in school I am trying to derive a parametrization of a klein bottle. I am starting by creating a tubular/canal surface around the space curve *p*:

$$x(t)=5(1+\sin(t))$$

$$y(t)=3\cos(t)(1+\sin(t))$$

$$z(t)=0$$

which is essentially a piriform curve lying on the $x$-$y$ plane. I hope to achieve an end product that looks something like [this](http://web1.kcn.jp/hp28ah77/fig19_39.gif). I have tried using the Frenet-serret formulas for the TNB frame using [these formulas](https://slideplayer.com/slide/4635438/15/images/93/SUMMARY+We+summarize+the+formulas+for+unit+tangent%2C+unit+normal+and+binormal+vectors%2C+and+curvature..jpg) instead of [differentiating them with respect to arc length](https://image1.slideserve.com/3381901/frenet-frame-arc-length-parameterization-l.jpg), as I realized that arc length could not be expressed as an elementary function in this particular case.

This was all so I could find the orthogonal basis by which I could parameterize a tubular/canal surface using the equation: $$p(u)+R(\cos(v)N(u)+\sin(v)B(u))$$

As I expected, the computations were quite tedious and I ended up having really long equations by the time I found the normal and binormal vectors. I plugged in them into the equation to form my surface, I chose the radius R to be $2$. For example:

$$x(u,v)= 5(1+\sin(u)) + 2(\cos(v)N(u)+\sin(v)B(u))$$

I didn't write out the actual normal and binormal vectors above as they are quite long, but basically I swapped out the *t* for *u*. However, when I plugged my equations into the geogebra surface plotter, I did not end up with my desired surface. I have checked my calculations, although having done them by hand, it is still prone to error.

**Is there an error in my process?** I was thinking that perhaps this particular curve may be a special case since the surface ends up intersecting itself, like a klein bottle self-intersecting in R3, or perhaps because of the nature of the piriform curve? If my method is wrong, what went wrong and how can I change it to eventually develop it for the parametrization of a klein bottle?

Ps- what are some good differentiation/integration calculators online for absurdly long equations which I can copy in format?

Comment: Your strategy sounds okay. Thinking about how I would try to do this, I would take a square with edges identified so that you a Klein bottle, and look for functions on this square that are compatible with the identifications, and use those to try to construct the map into space. That seems potentially easier than trying to write down the Frenet frame.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. What discrete maths can I research to do this method? I am only in high school so how should I go about this with close to zero knowledge?

Comment: I don't know what "discrete" means in this context. A Klein bottle is formed by taking a square, gluing the top and bottom to each other exactly, and gluing the left and right to each other with the top of the left glued to the bottom of the right, and vice versa. If you find functions with these properties, you might be able to use them.

Comment: Sorry, I guess a better word would have been "specific". I just need some key words to aid in my research.